# What's this strangely marked control on my Eclipse?

Tags: mitsubishi, hvac, eclipse

My 1995 Mitsubishi Eclipse, and presumably other Mitsubishis of the same era, has a control over by the rear windshield wiper control, near the center vents.  It's got 2 pictures of a person sitting.  The bottom half of both pictures is black.  The top image has the top portion in blue.  The bottom image has the top portion in white.  I presume it has something to do with the vent/hvac control system, but I don't know what.  I've tried flipping it between the 2 positions numerous times, but can't tell a difference in anything.  What *does* this mystery control do!?

Comment: What year is the Eclipse? Also, if you could edit this and put a picture of what you are talking about (either of your own or one from Google Images), it would help tremendously.

Comment: Have you checked the owner's manual?  They nearly always have a diagram of all the dashboard controls with a description of each one.

Comment: I'm thinking the two images you are talking about are the ones located around the directional for the HVAC, the one which adjusts where the breeze blowing is headed. If so, these two are probably the vented (white - normal A/C) and recirculated (blue - also called "max-A/C"). But since I don't know even what "dial" you are talking about, nor where you are actually referring to, I'm leaving this as a comment.

Comment: Did you ever get this sorted, Brian?

Comment: Negative.  I've even asked a few Mitsubishi mechanics and they don't know.  The control on mine is actually jammed halfway now so I attempted to trace where it went (in the hopes of both fixing it and figuring out what it does), but the back of the center console is so jam packed with stuff that I couldn't trace it.  I've got the OEM service manuals, and if it's detailed in there, I just haven't found it yet.  Hasn't been a high priority though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This switch allows you to deliver cool air from the center vents while heating with the mode selection knob in heating, heating and defrosting or defrosting position..

When the siwtch is upward (blue), there's cold air coming out of the center vents and hot air from the side vents.
When the switch is downward (white), hot air is coming out of all vents.

[image]